# Margin of Container not Applying Correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm having some issues with the margin property in CSS. I have each section tag as a different color, and I contained all of the content in each section in a div. My intention is to have a container that deals with the margins of the content, while also keeping the section tags touching together. However, below I have provided my code and a screenshot of the outcome. It would seem like the margin is applying to the sections and separating them, as opposed to the content containers. Does anybody know why this is and what a better way of writing this is?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <body>
    <main class="card-container">
      <section class="sec-1">
        <div class="content-container">
          <h1>Join our community</h1>
          <h3>30-day, hassle-free money back guarantee</h3>
          <p>Gain access to our full library of tutorials along  with expert code reviews. 
          Perfect for any developers who are serious about honing their skills.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="sec-2">
        <div class="content-container">
          <h2>Monthly Subscription</h2>
          <p>$29 per month</p>
          <p>Full access for less than $1 a day</p>
          <div class="btn-container">
            <button>Sign Up</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="sec-3">
        <div class="content-container">
          <h2>Why us</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>Tutorials by industry experts</li>
            <li>Peer & expert code review</li>
            <li>Coding exercises</li>
            <li>Access to our GitHub repos</li>
            <li>Community forum</li>
            <li>Flashcard decks</li>
            <li>New videos every week</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Karla:wght@400;700&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: hsl(204, 43%, 93%);
}

.card-container {
    margin: 0 2rem;
}

.content-container {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}


.sec-1 {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: black;
}

.sec-2 {
    background-color: hsl(179, 62%, 43%);
}

.sec-3 {
    background-color: hsla(179, 62%, 43%, 0.806);
}


ul {
    list-style: none;
}
```

[image: screenshot]

and here is the desired outcome for reference:

[image]

I have tried doing this in a separate project and it worked, but this particular project is being stubborn.

Answer (score 1):

Use padding because you have to provide space inside, not outside:

**Margin:** Space outside the element, affecting its position in relation to other elements.

**Padding:** Space inside the element, affecting the distance between the content and the element's border.

```
.content-container {
    padding: 2rem;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Karla:wght@400;700&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: hsl(204, 43%, 93%);
}

.card-container {
    margin: 0 2rem;
}

.content-container {
    padding: 2rem;
}


.sec-1 {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: black;
}

.sec-2 {
    background-color: hsl(179, 62%, 43%);
}

.sec-3 {
    background-color: hsla(179, 62%, 43%, 0.806);
}


ul {
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Document</title>
 
</head>
<body>
  <body>
    <main class="card-container">
      <section class="sec-1">
        <div class="content-container">
          <h1>Join our community</h1>
          <h3>30-day, hassle-free money back guarantee</h3>
          <p>Gain access to our full library of tutorials along  with expert code reviews. 
          Perfect for any developers who are serious about honing their skills.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="sec-2">
        <div class="content-container">
          <h2>Monthly Subscription</h2>
          <p>$29 per month</p>
          <p>Full access for less than $1 a day</p>
          <div class="btn-container">
            <button>Sign Up</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="sec-3">
        <div class="content-container">
          <h2>Why us</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>Tutorials by industry experts</li>
            <li>Peer & expert code review</li>
            <li>Coding exercises</li>
            <li>Access to our GitHub repos</li>
            <li>Community forum</li>
            <li>Flashcard decks</li>
            <li>New videos every week</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand still. If margin is space outside of the element, doesn't that mean that the container div would be pushed away from the section?

Comment: The margin doesn't push the entire container away; rather, it creates space between the container's border and other elements. The container's border remains where it is, but the space around it (margin) increases.

When we say "space outside the element" with respect to margin, it refers to the space outside the element's border, not the container itself. The margin is the space between the border of the element and the adjacent elements.